# How to mount a encrypted MS Windows 7 partition in Linux?

Tags: windows, ntfs, disk-encryption

I have a dual-boot Windows 7 and Linux Mint. In Windows 7 I have 2 partitions, 1 for the system (C:) and another for data (D:). The data partition was encrypted with Bitlocker. I can use it in Windows 7 because I have the password.

Linux Mint automatically mounts the Windows 7 Partition (type HPFS/NTFS, at `/dev/sda2`), so I can see that partition in the file manager (Nemo, or Thunar). But I can't see my data partition (type HPFS/NTFS, at `/dev/sda3`).

My system informations are the following:

```
$ inxi -S
System:    Host: desktop Kernel: 3.19.0-32-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 2.8.8  Distro: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.19.0-32-generic (buildd@lgw01-43) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015
```

How can I access my data in the encrypted partition on Linux?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux

Comment: @coffeMug if you want to turn that into an answer I'll withdraw (or ask the Mods to withdraw) my Community Wiki answer

Answer (score 4):

The solution given to this question over on SuperUser deserves its own cross-reference here. Note that this answer here is a Community Wiki so none of us get credit for the replication.

[How to access a BitLocker-encrypted drive in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux)

The Github code checkins are recent so - as of May 2016 - this is still an [active project](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/tree/develop).

Answer (score -3):

Being that you have encrypted your data partition, you have enhanced the security of the partition and have made it difficult to access (especially from another operating system).  In order to see this partition in Linux and to have the capability to read and write to it, you can remove the encryption using Windows and then you should have no problems accessing it within Linux.

Comment: "Disable encryption" is no valid answer to "How to decrypt".